# What is the purpose of -p, --project-name option in docker-compose command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

What is the purpose of -p or --project-name option in docker-compose command?

What is the use case for it?

I am a newbie and havent yet started docker networking. Is --project-name used there in docker networking?

When I add docker support in Visual Studio 2019, Visual Studio runs some docker compose command which look like below. In each of them, there is a -p option. I am curious about that.

```
docker-compose  -f "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDokWeb\DokWeb3\docker-compose.yml" -f "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDokWeb\DokWeb3\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDokWeb\DokWeb3\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose5511081461456614166 --no-ansi config
docker-compose  -f "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDokWeb\DokWeb3\docker-compose.yml" -f "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDokWeb\DokWeb3\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDokWeb\DokWeb3\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose5511081461456614166 --no-ansi build
docker-compose  -f "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDokWeb\DokWeb3\docker-compose.yml" -f "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDokWeb\DokWeb3\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDokWeb\DokWeb3\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose5511081461456614166 --no-ansi up -d --no-build --force-recreate --remove-orphans
```

I have seen the docker docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name) and also [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name), but could not get much from there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you run `docker-compose` multiple times, it uses the project name to keep one directory's containers, networks, and volumes separate from another's.  Compose doesn't keep any filesystem state or run a background daemon, so metadata on the containers is the only way to keep track of this.

Say you have three Compose projects, and `project-a/docker-compose.yml`, `project-b/docker-compose.yml`, and `project-c/docker-compose.yml` all have a service named `db:`.  Because their project names are different, Compose knows that it shouldn't reuse one `db` container for another project, it knows which container should be destroyed by `docker-compose down`, and so on.

A `docker-compose -p` option is required if you want to run multiple copies of the same Compose stack in the same directory.  Otherwise the directory name is used as the default project name, and they'd conflict with each other.  That's probably what Visual Studio is thinking about.

If you look at `docker ps`, `docker network ls`, and `docker volume ls` output you will see the name included in object names, `project-a_db_1`.  If you use the detailed `inspect` forms of these commands you will see some Compose-related labels, and these are what Compose actually looks for.

Comment: Is `-p` is same as `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable?

Comment: Yes, they do the same thing.  If you do use the `docker-compose -p` option, you need to provide it to _every_ invocation of the `docker-compose` tool; if you `export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=...` then it will be available in the background without a command-line option.

Comment: Why COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME is not visible when I put int into env file which was specified via --env-file?

Comment: **A docker-compose -p option is required if you want to run multiple copies of the same Compose stack in the same directory.** => That statement captures the gist and instantly helped me make sense of a complex shell script that was using it.

Answer (score 4):

By default, Compose bases the project name on `basename` of the directory compose
commands are run from. The project name can be overridden either by
passing a `-p / --project-name` option for each command or setting the
`COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable.

Use case is basically to maintain different projects with this. For e.g.:- You can use same `docker-compose.yml` to have 2 different projects.

In the command which you mentioned

```
docker-compose  -f "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDokWeb\DokWeb3\docker-compose.yml" -f "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDokWeb\DokWeb3\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDokWeb\DokWeb3\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose5511081461456614166 --no-ansi config
docker-compose  -f "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDokWeb\DokWeb3\docker-compose.yml" -f "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDokWeb\DokWeb3\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDokWeb\DokWeb3\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose5511081461456614166 --no-ansi build
docker-compose  -f "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDokWeb\DokWeb3\docker-compose.yml" -f "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDokWeb\DokWeb3\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDokWeb\DokWeb3\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose5511081461456614166 --no-ansi up -d --no-build --force-recreate --remove-orphans
```

If you see, it's manipulating the same project and that's why `-p` is given.